# POST,PUT,DELETE Methods are not working in swagger ui but GET Works

Tags: php, curl, swagger, libcurl, swagger-ui

POST, PUT and DELETE methods are not working in swagger UI but GET works for all my endpoints.

I even tried copy paste executing the curl command on shell and it is also working.

Is there any configuration I have to do in my server or swagger json to overcome this issue?

Comment: What version of Swagger UI?  3.0.x?  2.2.x?  Also, did you look at the debug console in your browser to inspect the HTTP request?

Comment: Swagger UI version v2.2.8

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after spend more than 8 hours I trace reason.

It is annotations issue in swagger json, You can try original annotation example from https://editor.swagger.io/# save it as swagger.json and try that in your project. It will show you results for trace.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, this is because some errors in my swagger docs. After I copy it to the https://editor.swagger.io/# and fix the problems. Now it works.
The fixes in my own project is https://github.com/liudonghua123/todolist-rest-apis/commit/3aa69e732991f1fd3d2a0891603784e2618d0405.

[image]